# Buying Prepaid Card

Tags: fiqh, riba

Anyone knows the ruling of prepaid card such as google play and steam wallet? say in Amazon US it costs 20 dollar to buy 20 Dollar gift card, but in my country it will cost IDR 22k for 20k, it looks like a riba but is it? although there is also gift card in dollar for steam wallet, but it will be converted in local currency as soon as you redeem it which means the amount maybe different from the price you paid.

Comment: It's not Riba, but the service charge which is allowed. look for the definition of Riba.

Comment: I suspected the 2k surplus is either a tax or service charge but not really sure, if it wasnt it looks like you are exchanging money for money if either receive more would be considered riba fadhl, Wallahualam